# Buildroot image missing /sys/bus/usb

Tags: usb, buildroot, beagleboneblack

I've tried to create a Beaglebone Black image with buildroot starting from beaglebone-defconfig.

I discovered that `/sys/bus/usb` seems to be missing:

```
# ls /sys/bus
clockevents   gpio          mmc_rpmb      scsi          workqueue
clocksource   hid           nvmem         sdio
container     i2c           pci           serial
cpu           mdio_bus      pci-epf       soc
event_source  mmc           platform      spi
```

I checked the kernel configuration and `Support for Host-side USB` was configured as a module.

I tried plugging in a USB drive, and couldn't find any new messages in `dmesg`. If fact there are no usb related entries (`dmesg | grep usb` returns nothing)

Could this be a device tree issue, or a kernel configuration issue? How can I go about debugging something like this?

Comment: could you look at the output of "dmesg | grep usb", please? maybe there is a warning or error in the kernel ring buffer?

Comment: why did you configure host-side USB as a module? that sounds like it's your problem; it should be built in... I'm almost dead-positive that is your problem ...also, generally speaking; it wouldn't hurt to double-check the defconfigs for your board, as well - in case you've missed other things.

Comment: @jrdnjhntsn `dmesg | grep usb` returns nothing. I didn't change anything from the default. I'll try making it built-in rather than as a module.

Comment: @jrdnjhntsn I tried out making host support built-in but it didn't make any noticeable difference

Comment: your board obviously ships with a compiled kernel, correct? do you know if it contains; /proc/config.gz (the running kernel's kernel config) -- assuming this kernel's usb does work?

Comment: @jrdnjhntsn ooops, I was accidentally copying the wrong file. Switching to built-in on a whole bunch of stuff got it to work. I'll try to figure out which ones specifically were required and write it up.

Comment: ah ok. good to hear. I knew something was up with things being built as modules, rather than built-in. I thought it odd that the host-side USB was a module. I suppose that was a bit of a hint, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out changing several modules to be built-in (rather than included as a module) seems to have fixed the problem.

I followed this [post](https://otm.my.id/2019/05/24/introduction-to-buildroot-and-enabling-usb-in-beaglebone-black-bbb-buildroot-part-1/), ignoring everything to do with sound.

So it boilded down to changing these configs:

```
– Device Drivers
– – USB support (USB-
– – – <*> Support for Host-side USB
– – – <*> EHCI HCD (USB 2.0) support
– – – [*] Root Hub Transaction Translator
– – – <*> EHCI support for OMAP3 and later chips
– – – <*> OHCI HCD (USB 1.1) support
– – – <*> OHCI support for OMAP3 and later chips
— – <*> INVENTRA Highspeed Dual Role Controller (TI, ADI, AW, …)
– – – <*> TI DSPS platforms
```